# How to add childerens to wxColourDialog

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I tried to add childrens to wxColourDialog using sizer class, but wxColourDialog is returning NULL wxSizer if i use

```
wxsizer *sizer = this->GetSizer();
```

Is there any way to add childrens to wxColourDialog

Answer (score 0):

On most platforms `wxColourDialog` is a native dialog and doesn't use sizers and can't be customized (this is true for almost all the other native dialogs too, [wxFileDialog](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_file_dialog.html#aa312b8ae7961060c3116457c6334b527) being the only exception).

You may use its generic version (`wxGenericColourDialog`) if you really need to have a custom dialog.